# disable the options of a Windows 8 not-responding app

Tags: windows

On [Microsoft website I saw this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130618054947/http://windows.microsoft.com:80/en-us/windows7/what-does-it-mean-when-a-program-is-not-responding):

> What does it mean when a program is not responding?
>
> If a program is not responding, it means the program is interacting more slowly than usual with Windows, typically because a problem has occurred in the program. If the problem is temporary, and if you choose to wait, some programs will start responding again. Depending on the options available, you can also choose to close or restart the program.

On Windows 8, how do you DISABLE "the options" so that users of my application do not see the options to restart my app?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing your application's design so that this situation doesn't arise.  "Not responding" afaik means that the thread with the main message pump is not fetching messages.  This is not a good thing to allow to happen.

It's better to do things that will take a long time in a separate thread, and keep responding to the user in the meantime (even if this just means asking them to wait and keeping a dialog responding to mouse events etc).